# Problems creating a pure css submenu with a dropdown animation

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, css

Hello I have this problem that I can't make my submenu to work properly, 
I am a beginning programmer so maybe my code isn't totally right (obvious if something doesn't work XD)
I want it to work so that if I hover over a link in de menubar, a submenu fades in, it's ok if there is some jquery involved to get the solution.
But could someone take a look at what I do wrong and tell me how I should be doing it?
Thanks in advance,
Sander

Here's the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<body>
<div id="Menu">
        <ul class="ulMenu">                 
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Slideshow</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!--menu end-->
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS code (Its quite big because I probably do some things double):

```
    #menu{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2),        inset 0 10px 20px     rgba(255,255,255,0.25),                 inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu ul li ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    top:50px;
    width: 80px;
    background: #444;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px    rgba(255,255,255,0.25),inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#menu ul li ul:hover{
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}

#menu li{
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#menu li a,#menu li a:visited{
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 89px 0 13px;
    transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
}

#menu li a:hover{
    color: #1c478e;
}
```

Comment: hi codehorse, it is working but now when I hover over the submenu link itself (so not the menu link as it supposed to be working) the submenu fades in, but I want it so that if I hover over the menu links the submenu fades in.

Answer (score 2):

Change `:hover` to `<li>`

http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/XvGAb/

```
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Ow thank's alot guys such a simple thing but I just could not get it right!

Comment: @user3123507 Accept this as the answer please, unless you need another solution.

Comment: I have another problem now, when I hover over the submenu section even if it is not visible it shows up, so now it shows up when I hover over the menu link above the submenu (wich is perfect) but also when I hover over the invisible location of the submenu. Meaning that I can't use content that's under the section of the submenu

Answer (score 0):

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/elvbq)

try it and compare
HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">My Dashboard</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="learn">Learn</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="teach">Teach</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="Mylibrary">My Library</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Likes</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="Pics">Pictures</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="audio">Audio</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="Videos">Videos</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Views</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="signout">Videos</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">account</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="SI">Sign In</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="Reg">Register</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="Deactivate">Deactivate</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Uploads</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="Pics">Pictures</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="audio">Audio</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="Videos">Videos</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="Add">Add</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Documents</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="Add">Upload</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="delete">Download</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.menu, .menu ul, .menu li, .menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
body {
    max-width:110%;
    margin-left:0;
}
.menu {
    height: 40px;
    width:110%;
    margin-left:-4px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li:first-child a {
    border-left: none;
}
.menu li:last-child a {
    border-right: none;
}
.menu li:hover > a {
    color: #8fde62;
}
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #1f2024;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation what you did to make the code working.

Comment: You gave that me? - Your question was automatically flagged as low quality and I did review it. And the big difference between your answer and the above is that yours contains loads of unimportant code and no explanation what you changed. (The first sentences in the above answer)